# Apache Impala optimisation for high cardinality fields

Tags: sql, hadoop, database-design, business-intelligence, impala

I need to create a table for Apache Impala that will store large amount of data.
The structure is following:

```
time_key date
organization_name string
client_id string
kpi1
kpi2
...
```

The goal is to store data in a way that it will have the lowest possible latency when queried by specific **time_key**, **organization_name** and **client_id**.

I can make **time_key** and **organization_name** fields a partition keys cause of low cardinality. But the **client_id** field has millions of unique values. So i guess that partitioning based on hdfs directories won't work.

**client_id** is represented by digits only and it's length is fixed.

Im thinking about few options:

- Create fixed number of partitions for **client_id** field, each represents the certain interval, e.g. the first or last digit of id
- Is there any use of Hive bucketing? Im not sure that impala is capable of using it, and i'm not sure that it affects table scan speed at all.
- I didn' find anything about it, but maybe Impala have some kind of indexes or similar feature?

At the moment i have no opportunity to test Impala with real data on real cluster, so i need to make right guess about storing **client_id** field.

What will be the correct way?

Comment: _"lowest possible latency when queried by [composite key ID]"_ >> this has nothing to do with "Business Intelligence" and OLAP. If you really want a low-latency key/value DB, look into HBase, Cassandra etc.

Comment: For the record, Apache CarbonData is a (pretty experimental) Hadoop file format which is columnar with min/max metadata, for Skip Scan access -- like ORC or Parquet -- but also with embedded indexes, for Key access. But it is designed for Spark; the Hive interface is just out and not battle-tested.

Comment: For the record also, Cloudera has released Kudu which is a kind of hybrid of HBase and HDFS, with a (crude) Impala interface. It is supposed to allow for "faster" By-Key queries; but the primary goal was to allow for streaming inserts (which HDFS was not designed for).

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thank you for your reply, the info was useful.